# How can I set a logo in the "Sign in with Apple" consent screen?

Tags: oauth-2.0, apple-sign-in

[image]

I'm implementing 'Sign in with Apple'. How do I use my own app icon on the "Sign in with Apple" consent page instead of displaying a placeholder gray logo?

Answer (score 3):

The app icon displayed in the web flow, in addition to the native Sign in with Apple sheet, will be the App Store icon for the primary application associated with your website. If you do not have an app in the App Store to associate your website with, the placeholder app icon will be displayed instead.

Refer to [Configure Sign In with Apple for the web](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/configure-app-capabilities/configure-sign-in-with-apple-for-the-web) for information regarding associating your website with an app.

Comment: I have configured the domain and the return URLs. The Sign in with Apple button is put under “https://{example.com}/home”
I fill in “{example.com}“ as Web Domain.
The whole sign in flow is working smoothly, except the logo does not display.
Any one can help?

Comment: As explained above, the app icon is fetched from the App Store. You need to have an associated bundle ID set to an application that is currently available on the Mac or iOS App Store for the icon to display. I wrote the logic for this.

Comment: @DaveAMoore: if an app is in TestFlight status and not publicly available, is that good enough to obtain an icon?

Comment: This has got to be one of the most absurd things I've come across (so far) with Sign in with Apple. Would it have killed them to allow a custom png file be uploaded and set for the Sign in with Apple app in question? Ohnoooo too difficult.

Comment: @IncredibleHat: Sign in with Apple is intended for use with applications that are available on Apple platforms through the App Store. Using approved app icons available through the App Store avoids potential abuse. It was not too difficult, but rather an explicit decision. If you feel the feature you describe should be added, please use [Feedback Assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/welcome) to file an ER.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, already submitted... but it will never go anywhere like all the other suggestions our app devs have put in over the decades. I stand behind my absurdity statement, because apple has their own way of doing things, and no one outside of apple is ever right. Its just a way of life.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `app id`:

   Specify `bundle name` **the same as you have in your iOS app** (specified in info.plist of your app).
2. Create `service id`:

   Specify app id above. Associate it with website.
3. Go to [identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list)->open app id->Scroll down to sign in with apple->hit `edit`->Choose `set as primary app id`.