# application icon does not appear under Apps Using Apple ID

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

All app icon sizes are correct in assets catalog, but app icon does not appear under Apps Using Apple ID in device settings. Is there another place to set app icon for sign in with apple?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in other answers, the app icon for the Apple ID stuff is pulled from the app store:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58653699/793607

> "As explained above, the app icon is fetched from the App Store. You
>   need to have an associated bundle ID set to an application that is
>   currently available on the Mac or iOS App Store for the icon to
>   display. I wrote the logic for this"